# How can I recover gear from my dead companion's missing body?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I had Faendal as a follower, and I had armor on him that is not replaceable. So what does he do? He goes and dies.

I don't really want him as a follower anymore, but I did the whole `player.moveto (id)` thing and when I go to where he died, there's no body. I tried to enable him, to resurrect him, all that fun stuff but its just an empty spot. Any way to fix this or do I just have to cheat and add the armor in that way?

Comment: Did you check the Dead Body Cleanup Cell? Usually, all "important" corpses go there. Try `coc WIDeadBodyCleanupCell` And check if hes there.

Comment: I'm amused that you think adding the armour back in is cheating but none of what you've mentioned in your question is.

Comment: @YUNOWORK I went to this room, and there was 2 empty coffins and a man named Malborn, nothing else.

Comment: @shanodin I have different types of "cheat levels," Its a bit hypocritical, but I consider using cheats to find the body ok while spawning items isnt.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using his base ID + Resurrection??

Here is his base id : 00013480

And here is the wikia page , quite useful : http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Faendal

Comment: So Did It Work??

Comment: I tried this earlier, nothing happened.

Comment: @Superfly, did an error message pop up when you tried to use the code. Also, make sure you use the RefID

Comment: @AhkamNihardeen No error message, in fact, nothing happened. And yes, I used the Ref.

Comment: Have you tried  in multiple areas? Opened the character it CK or TES5EDIT and see if there is an issue there?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `removeallitems` or `duplicateallitems` command.

```
prid refID1
removeallitems refID2
```

This should move all items from from `refID1` to `refID2`.
I think the oneliner `refID1.removeallitems refID2` should work as well.